# How to pass a member of a struct to a function by reference in C?

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to pass a member of a stuct to a function in c by reference and then use it to access the same member of a struct of the same type.

```
typedef struct Node
{
int a;
int b;
int c;
} Node;

Node mynode; //global

void pass_member(int *member){
   mynode.&member = 1;//gives a compiler error
}

void main()
{
 mynode.a = 0;
 mynode.b = 45;
 mynode.c = 64;

 pass_member(&mynode.a)
}
```

I can see that `mynode.&member` is not allowed in c but i think it shows what i am trying to do

is it possible to pass the address of an member of a struct to a function in c 
 and then use it to access that member in a struct of the same type?

basically what i am trying to achieve is a function somthing like this

`void set_member(int value_to_set, int * pointer_to_member_of_which_to_set);`

that would set a specific member of a global struct depending on the given member to the function.

Comment: `mynode.&member = 1;` --> `*member = 1;`

Comment: "what i am trying to achieve is a function... that would set a specific member of a global struct depending on the given member to the function"  This is the root of the problem. Don't write such silly functions, this program design is bad. In particular, using a global variable shared with the function and the caller is very bad. Instead, simply write in the caller: `mynode.a = whatever;`.

Comment: Basically, there's only two valid cases of program design here. Either the caller knows the nature of the struct and then the caller can change it. Or the caller does not know the nature of the struct - because the struct is _privately encapsulated_ - in which case the members of the struct is of no business of the caller.

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/x2GxCE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you some example first:-

You can do it like this `func(&mynode)`.

And `func` is `void func(Node* aa)`

Now you can use it like this

`aa->a = aa->a + 1` etc.

Most of the time you will send the address of the whole structure rather than the address of the individiual element.

- `Node aa` => aa is of type struct node (typedefed to Node)
- It's address: `&aa`
- `aa.a` is the element of the structure `aa` and it's address is `&aa.a`

#### Solution-1

> ```
> void pass_member(int *member){
>    *member = 1;
> }
> ```

```
  pass_member(&mynode.a) // in main()
```

---

#### Solution-2

Also you can use it like this:-

```
typedef struct Node
{
int a;
int b;
int c;
} Node;

Node mynode; //global

void pass_member(Node *member){
   (*member).a = 1;//member->a = 1
}

void main()
{
 mynode.a = 0;
 mynode.b = 45;
 mynode.c = 64;

 pass_member(&mynode)
}
```

You asked **is it possible to pass the address of an member of a struct to a function in c?**

Ans: Yes it is possible, it is shown in the answer.

**and then use it to access that member in a struct of the same type?**

You can access that memebr be it of some struct or some other struct. As long as it is a pointer to an appropriate type it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either pass pointer to the member variable as

```
void pass_member(int *member){
  *member = 1;
```

and

```
 pass_member(&mynode.a);
```

OR pass pointer to the entire structure

```
void pass_member(Node *member){
  (*member).a = 1; //or member->a = 1; as pointed out in comments
```

and

```
pass_member(&mynode)
```

Comment: `(*member).a = 1;` can be written simply as `member->a = 1;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `offsetof` to get the relative address of a member. I am unaware of a reverse operation (don't do much in C), but it can be simulated like this:

```
#define offsetin(s,a,t) *((t*)(((char*)&s)+a))
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
void pass_member(size_t member){
    offsetin(mynode, member, int) = 1;
}

void main()
{
    mynode.a = 0;
    mynode.b = 45;
    mynode.c = 64;

    pass_member(offsetof(Node,a));
}
```